# What module i need to install to see my header variables in $_SERVER array?

Tags: php, apache, variables, server

I had a server where i have a php file to which i pass some header variables and read it in the PHP file as follows...

```
 $_SERVER["HTTP_API_KEY"]
```

If i pass `API_KEY` in my header data i get the value in server as `$_SERVER["HTTP_API_KEY"]`. Now my code has been moved to new server and there i do not see `$_SERVER["HTTP_API_KEY"]` in my `$_SERVER` array! 
It could be either PHP module or Apache module that i may need to configure with server i believe. I tried to find solution but unlucky to get one yet.

Let me know if anyone knows exactly what it is...

Comment: What do you mean by `pass API_KEY in my header data`?  Is it part of a get or post request?

Comment: Hi Julie, thanks for the reply. It is not GET or POST data... its header data... i do able to read data with getallheaders() function in PHP... but i need to change full project as everywhere it was coded to use $_SERVER to read this data... so wondering if there is a way to get it work on my new server too...

Comment: Are you still using the same web server?  (Apache vs Nginx)

Comment: Have you done a print_r($_SERVER) and print_r($GLOBALS) to see if anything?

Comment: @JuliePelletier - yes it is the same apache server with php 7

Comment: @Brogan - yes i do get other server variables like IP address, Referer, etc... data... but not the headers am passing...

Comment: You might want to check out this function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php print_r(getallheaders());

Answer (score 1):

I would give the [getallheaders](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) function a try!

If you want to add the key back into the $_SERVER array, just add this to the top of your file.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY']) && isset(getallheaders()['API_KEY']))
    $_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY'] = getallheaders()['API_KEY'];

?>
```

---

To grab the first available key.

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY']))
    $key = $_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY'];
elseif(isset(getallheaders()['API_KEY']))
    $key = getallheaders()['API_KEY'];
else
    die('Key not found.');

?>
```

---

Adapted to include keys from Get and Post requests.

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY']))
    $key = $_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY'];
elseif(isset(getallheaders()['API_KEY']))
    $key = getallheaders()['API_KEY'];
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['API_KEY']))
    $key = $_POST['API_KEY'];
elseif(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && isset($_GET['API_KEY']))
    $key = $_GET['API_KEY'];
else
    die('Key not found.');

if($key !== '12345')
    die('Invalid key.');

echo 'Hello world!';

?>
```

Comment: Hi Brogan i can read data through getallheaders() function... i mentioned it in my previous comment... but what i need to know is which module in PHP/Apache is handling this ? so i will not have to do lot of code modifications...

Comment: I'm not absolutely familiar with how PHP7 handles custom headers, but you might find that they are no longer merged with the $_SERVER variable and no plugin may solve this issue. I recommend the single line solution of just replacing the missing variable. Insert it once before any other code and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I found by trial and error:

In `Apache/php` environment, HTTP header of `API-KEY` become `$_SERVER['HTTP_API_KEY']`

Note `-` becomes `_`.

A header of `API_KEY` does not propagate to `$_SERVER`